# How to add a calculated column to a data frame in the middle of a series of joins of other data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Suppose we perform a series of `left_join()` of data frames as shown below (please don't worry about appropriateness of `left_join()`, this is a simple example drawn from larger code which does require `left_join()`):

```
library(dplyr)

mydat <- data.frame(period = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), plusA = c(10,20,12,13,17,19,20,16))
    
minus_B <- data.frame(period = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), minusB = c(8,18,10,11,18,9,12,4))
    
equals_D <- data.frame(period = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), equalsD = c(18,28,20,21,28,19,22,14))
    
mydat %>%
      left_join(minus_B) %>%
      left_join(equals_D)
    
  period plusA minusB equalsD
1      1    10      8      18
2      2    20     18      28
3      3    12     10      20
4      4    13     11      21
5      5    17     18      28
6      6    19      9      19
7      7    20     12      22
8      8    16      4      14
```

I'm trying to add a balancing column, called "adjC", between the "minusB" and "equalsD" columns, that would leave a data frame output of:

```
  period plusA minusB  adjC equalsD  [Explain column adjC]
1      1    10      8    16      18   18 - (10 - 8) = 16
2      2    20     18    26      28   28 - (20 - 18) = 26
3      3    12     10    18      20   etc.
4      4    13     11    19      21
5      5    17     18    27      28
6      6    19      9     9      19
7      7    20     12    16      22
8      8    16      4     2      14
```

I've been fooling around with `mydat %>% mutate(adjust_C = equalsD - (plusA - minusB))`, or inserting it into the middle of the above `left_join()` series, and it doesn't work.

Any ideas how to do this? I'm trying to stick with dplyr too.

Comment: Do you need `mydat %>%
      left_join(minus_B) %>%
       left_join(equals_D) %>% mutate(adj = equalsD - (plusA - minusB))`. The `mydat` is the original dataset before the `left_join` and it doesn't have those columns

Comment: Or else you may have to update the `mydat` i.e. `mydat  <- mydat %>%  left_join(minus_B) %>%
      left_join(equals_D)` which is not done in your code

Comment: Take it @akrun, your answer is likely correct given what we know

Comment: If your question is about creating column at a specific location use `.before` or `.after` in `mutate` (after the left_join) i.e. `%>% mutate(adjC = equalsD - (plusA - minusB), .before = 'equalsD')`

Comment: Yes exactly akrun, I need to create a new column in a specific location. I tried inserting the mutate() in the middle of the left_joins and the results were disastrous. I tried your solution and it works perfectly. I have a lot to learn and you´re a great teacher akrun!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the OP used `mutate` directly on the original dataset which was not updated

```
library(dplyr)
mydat %>% 
       left_join(minus_B) %>%  
       left_join(equals_D) %>% 
       mutate(adjC = equalsD - (plusA - minusB), .before = 'equalsD')
```

-output

```
   period plusA minusB adjC equalsD
1      1    10      8   16      18
2      2    20     18   26      28
3      3    12     10   18      20
4      4    13     11   19      21
5      5    17     18   29      28
6      6    19      9    9      19
7      7    20     12   14      22
8      8    16      4    2      14
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure are you looking for both, `adjC` and `explain_adjC`?:

```r
library(dplyr)

mydat %>%
  left_join(minus_B) %>%
  left_join(equals_D) %>% 
  mutate(adjC = equalsD - (plusA - minusB),
         .before = "equalsD") %>% 
  mutate(explain_adjC = paste0(equalsD, ' - (', plusA, ' - ', minusB, ') = ', adjC)
# alternatively with {glue}:
# mutate(explain_adjC = glue::glue("{equalsD} - ({plusA} - {minusB}) = {adjC}"))
)

#> Joining, by = "period"
#> Joining, by = "period"
#>   period plusA minusB adjC equalsD        explain_adjC
#> 1      1    10      8   16      18  18 - (10 - 8) = 16
#> 2      2    20     18   26      28 28 - (20 - 18) = 26
#> 3      3    12     10   18      20 20 - (12 - 10) = 18
#> 4      4    13     11   19      21 21 - (13 - 11) = 19
#> 5      5    17     18   29      28 28 - (17 - 18) = 29
#> 6      6    19      9    9      19   19 - (19 - 9) = 9
#> 7      7    20     12   14      22 22 - (20 - 12) = 14
#> 8      8    16      4    2      14   14 - (16 - 4) = 2


# data
mydat <- data.frame(period = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), plusA = c(10,20,12,13,17,19,20,16))

minus_B <- data.frame(period = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), minusB = c(8,18,10,11,18,9,12,4))

equals_D <- data.frame(period = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), equalsD = c(18,28,20,21,28,19,22,14))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I just needed the adjC column and not the [explain...] part. But both work perfectly in your response. That {glue} you show should come in handy too.

Answer (score 0):

This is admittedly a bit of a brute force solution, but why not just use base R syntax after your joins?  I think the behavior is an artifact of the joining in `dplyr::`.  Simply make your joins a dataframe, and create a new column.  Remember that R doesn't really care about column order for your data structure, so you can simply reorder your columns as desired.  Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)

mydat <- data.frame(period = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), plusA = c(10,20,12,13,17,19,20,16))

minus_B <- data.frame(period = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), minusB = c(8,18,10,11,18,9,12,4))

equals_D <- data.frame(period = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), equalsD = c(18,28,20,21,28,19,22,14))

JOINED<-data.frame(mydat %>%
  left_join(minus_B) %>%
  left_join(equals_D)) 

JOINED[,"adj_C"] <- (JOINED$equalsD - (JOINED$plusA - JOINED$minusB))
out<-JOINED[,c(1:3, 5, 4)]
out
```